# Match non-partitionKey fields (in nested json) in both tables and retrieve data in DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have 2 tables, with 1 matching data in which I want to utilize that as a matching field and retrieve some data.

First table is this:

```
{
      "mainFieldName": {
        "S": "someString"
      },
      "fieldA": {
        "L": [
          {
            "M": {
              "AccountId": {
                "S": "12345"
              },
              "PrincipalId": {
                "S": "randomIdString"
              },
              "PrincipalType": {
                "S": "GROUP"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "M": {
              "AccountId": {
                "S": "12345"
              },
              "PrincipalId": {
                "S": "secondRandomString"
              },
              "PrincipalType": {
                "S": "GROUP"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "fieldC": {
        "L": [
          {
            "M": {
              "name": {
                "S": "xxx"
              },
              "final_json": {
                "S": "some json data"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Second table:

```
{
  "userId": {
    "S": "randomString"
  },
  "group": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "GroupId": {
            "S": "randomGroupId"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to find the matched field for first table's `fieldA.PrincipalId` and second table's `group.GroupId`, if match, returning data is first table's `fieldC.final_json`

My params i tried is this, it's executed successfully but no results returned. I have confirmed there should be some matched inputs.

```
response = table1.scan(
                TableName=TABLE_1,
                FilterExpression="#gid.#pid = :id",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':id': {'S': groupId}
                },
                ExpressionAttributeNames={
                    '#gid': 'groupId',
                    '#pid': 'PrincipalId'
                }
                )
```

It always return empty results

Comment: Can you share an output of what you expect. You logic and description is really messed up here and its difficult to understand what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: thought i have shared all the info I have in the questions.. output expected is the stated "if match, returning data is first table's fieldC.final_json", but i got nothing returned instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to find a resolution to this. To simplify, I changed to a flatter table structure by pre-processing the Json to appending to a list.

My first table becomes:

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "randomString"
  },
  "fieldA": {
    "S": "randomString"
  },
  "table_1_groupId": {
    "L": [
      {
        "S": "randomGroupIdString"
      }
    ]
  },
  "fieldB": {
    "S": "asdfsafd"
  },
  "fieldC": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "name": {
            "S": "randomString"
          },
          "jsonData": {
            "S": "randomJsonData"
          },
          "type": {
            "S": "type_a"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Second table stays the same.

With that i am able to use DynamoDB query which is more efficient as well, with `FilterExpressions`

My query is:

```
response = table1.query(
                TableName=TABLE_1,
                KeyConditionExpression="id = :id",
                FilterExpression="contains(groupId, :gid)",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':id': defaultId,
                    ':gid': groupId
                },
)
```

My output returns list of all data (since I haven't added any filter to the output) once they have the field 'GroupId' in Table2 match with `table_1_groupId` in table 1